# In Objective-C, in a loop that performs intensive operations, would the use of @synchonized be beneficial to the stability of the implementation?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am writing a network Application in Objective-C for the Mac. At some point, I need to act just like a firewall, and inspect every packet I receive from a network interface. Long story short, I have two NSFileHandle objects, and the first has a readability handler:

```
[self.fileHandle setReadabilityHandler:^(NSFileHandle * _Nonnull handle) {
     NSData *data = [handle availableData];
     if (someCondition) {
         [self.outputFileHandle writeData:data];
     }
}];
```

This works, but is a lot unstable and tends to crash. While debugging, with a breakpoint on availableData, I could see that many times, the block is called before the previous one has finished executing. So I have thought of using @synchronized to prevent overflow, but I am not very experienced with it. So my code would become something like:

```
[self.fileHandle setReadabilityHandler:^(NSFileHandle * _Nonnull handle) {
    @synchronized (handle) {
         NSData *data = [handle availableData];
         if (someCondition) {
             [self.outputFileHandle writeData:data];
         }
    }
}];
```

My question is, is the synchronized pattern useful in this case ? How can I choose the right token to give to the block ? also, I have seen sometimes nested synchronized blocks. Can somebody with more experience suggest to me a good strategy in my situation ? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: If the goal is to prevent the block from being run multiple times simultaneously, that could obviously be a job for a GCD serial queue. Then the correct `handle` just falls into the GCD block.

Comment: If you want to determine whether synchronization is needed, you need to reason about your code and see if it’s potentially attempting simultaneous access from multiple threads. To this end, you can temporarily turn on the [thread sanitizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing_memory_thread_and_crash_issues_early) (TSAN) and see if it identifies some thread-unsafe access. If it does (or, as you have done, you can look at your code, you can identify obvious data races), then some synchronization mechanism, such as `@synchronized`, locks, or GCD, can be beneficial.

Comment: or check whole design pattern, because in the code you show its not clear if @synchronized would help at all. In example how many ports are opened and working simultaneously managed from one and the same handler filling data after parsing in one and the same resulting data chunk. PS. i wrote a OSC parser that handles multiple connections in&out with a ringbuffer filling always in front, popping the lastObjects. Also possible your outputFileHandle needs to copy the data in, instead of throwing pointers to data around.